# Webpack & React dynamic import chunk file not generated

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am using React@16.0.0 and webpack@3.1.0 to build a dashboard template and trying to generate chunk files from dynamic import but the files are never generated. :( I could render the component which is imported and rendered but it seems the file is not made and the component is not dynamically imported.

**What I did**

- Set "syntax-dynamic-import" and "dynamic-import-webpack" to babel plugin
- Added chunkFilename to webpack output

**What I expected**

- Generate chunk file out of dynamic import based on route

**Version**

- "react": "^16.0.0"
- "react-dom": "^16.0.0"
- "react-router": "^4.2.0"
- "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
- "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1"
- "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0"
- "webpack": "3.1.0"

Here is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "dynamic-import-webpack",
    "transform-export-extensions",
    "transform-class-properties",
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }],
    ["transform-object-rest-spread", {
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

And this is `App.jsx` and I tried to make chunk file out of **Dashboard1**

```
const loadDashboard1 = import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard1" */ '../Dashboard1/index.jsx')

const Dashboard1 = (props) => <AsyncComponent lazyLoadComponent={loadDashboard1} props={props} /> 
const Dashboard = () => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/dashboard/1" component={Dashboard1} /> //*** This should be dynamic imported and make chunk file
      <Route path="/dashboard/2" component={Dashboard2} />
      <Route path="/dashboard/3" component={Dashboard3} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
)


const App = () => (
  <div className={wrapper}>
    <HeaderMain />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={SidebarLeft} />
    <main className={content}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </div>
)

export default App
```

Here is my webpack.config.js. I added `chunkFilename`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  target: 'web',
  node: {
    __dirname: true,
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  entry: {
    'main': './client/index.js',
    'vendor': ['react', 'react-dom']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: "/public",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader',
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader',
        }]
      }, {
        test: /\.(scss)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          }, {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            }
          }, {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              config: {
                path: 'postcss.config.js'
              }
            }
          }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      title: ''
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')], {
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    })
  ]
};
```

Here is `AsyncComponent`.

```
import React from 'react'

class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    Component: null,
    isLoaded: false,
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const module = await this.props.lazyLoadComponent
    this.setState({
      Component: module.default ,
      isLoaded: true,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { Component } = this.state
    return (
      <div>{this.state.isLoaded ? <Component /> : this.props.loader}</div>
    )
  }
}


export default AsyncComponent
```

This is the result out of webpack

```
   main.5227b4d762a52f00aeb2.js     262 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    vendor.478de73b0c92dd129de6.js     116 kB       1  [emitted]         vendor
  main.5227b4d762a52f00aeb2.js.map    1.53 MB       0  [emitted]         main
vendor.478de73b0c92dd129de6.js.map     420 kB       1  [emitted]         vendor
                        index.html  297 bytes          [emitted]
```

If you have any idea to solve this issue or need further information, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: It's refreshing to see a solid question laid out with attempts and expectations, kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks perfect, minus the dynamic-import-webpack, which isn't needed in webpack 2+. My guess is that you imported this component somewhere else on accident, so the bundle wasn't created :)

Comment: I accidentally imported the component in a static way from other files, which causes that chunk file was not generated.